# TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' vs as alias during import

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am new to defining `self` and calling functions in another python file. I am using python 3.7. Suppose I have two python file, one with the class (name.py) and another calling this class function in another file (test.py). I am trying to understand why python shows error in Try#1 but not in the #2? Try#1 as defining as alias, but what does this do? It seems like it is not initializing it?

**Main file with class function: name.py**

```
class NameEmployee:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def first_name(self,x):
        return print('Hello ',x,'!')
```

**File to run: test.py**

Try #1: NOT WORKING

```
from names import NameEmployee as ne
ne.first_name(x = 'John')
```

**Results in --> TypeError: first_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'**

Try #2: WORKING

```
from names import NameEmployee
ne = NameEmployee()
ne.first_name(x = 'John')
```

**Results in --> Hello John !**

Comment: Are you aware that those codes are not equivalent? In the first code indeed `ne` is just an alias. It is an alias to the class. So just as you did `ne = NameEmployee()` in the second try to create an instance, you need to **call** the class in the first try: `ne().first_name(x='John')`

Comment: Yes, I know its alias. But didn't know you could use `()` for the alias. Thanks.

Comment: @sharp `()` is not creating an alias. These are *two totally different things*

Comment: Try reading about `classmethod` and `staticmethod`: https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to establish that this has nothing to do with "aliasing", rather the simple fact that the two pieces of code are not equivalent!

Let's start by simplifying the **Second try**. We will simply remove the use of an intermediate variable, to get:

```py
from names import NameEmployee
NameEmployee().first_name(x='John')
```

Now, going to the **first try**, let's just remove the alias for now:

```py
from names import NameEmployee
NameEmployee.first_name(x='John')
```

Now you can clearly see the difference: The second try actually **calls** (with those `()`) the constructor, thus implicitly passing `self` which is the newly created instance.

But the first try calls the `first_name` method directly from the **class**, and not an **instance** of the class, so `self` is never passed (`NameEmployee().first_name(x='John')` is equivalent to `NameEmployee.first_name(NameEmployee(), x='John')` while `NameEmployee.first_name(x='John')` is just what it is - a call to `first_name` without passing `self`...).

Let's reverse engineer:

- We now want to call the constructor, like try 2:

  ```py
  from names import NameEmployee
  NameEmployee().first_name(x='John')
  ```
- Now we want to alias:

  ```py
  from names import NameEmployee as ne
  ne().first_name(x='John')
  ```

  (Remember that aliasing is simply name replacement)
- Now if you want you can separate the object to a new variable:

  ```py
  from names import NameEmployee as ne
  name_employee = ne()
  name_employee.first_name(x='John')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you are not instantiating a `NameEmployee` object, so it cannot automatically pass a `self` object to the function. The second example is the correct way of using classes the way that you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You paid attention to this issue.you have to consider one of these two styles Only for libraries like os---(But NameEmployee is a class):

```
from os import path as p
```

or

```
import os.path as p
```

For more information go to:https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/

Comment: You can't do `names.NameEmployee` unless `names`  is a package which is not here... And anyway `NameEmployee` is a class so you can't just `import` it - you have to use `from ... import ...`

Comment: What do you mean? `NameEmployee` is a class, so anyway it is not possible to do `import names.NameEmployee`

Comment: I know. At first, I did not see the upper part of the problem that the NameEmployee class had introduced

Comment: Oh I see... Weird that's the main code in the question. Please fix your answer, right now it's wrong and misleading

Answer (score 0):

You need to **create a object** of the class to implement the methods of the class.
In the first example you didn't create a object and that's why a TypeError was risen.